# Row reduction error

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I'm having trouble with row reduction on the following matrix when I try to find the eigenvector for $\lambda$=1.

$\frac{1}{7} \times \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 6 & 3  \\
    6 & -3 & 2 \\
    3 & 2 & -6\\
\end{bmatrix}$
For $\lambda$ = 1 this becomes
$\frac{1}{7} \times \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 6 & 3  \\
    6 & -4 & 2 \\
    3 & 2 & -7\\
\end{bmatrix}$

But when I row reduce this I get

$\frac{1}{7} \times \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 6 & 3  \\
    0 & -40 & -16 \\
    0 & -16 & -16\\
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvector that I should be getting is (3,2,1). Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2,3} = -7, -7, 7$. That seems to be your error, you should be using $\lambda = 7$.

Comment: Why do you think that $\lambda=1$ should be an eigenvalue in the first place?  Your work clearly shows that for $\lambda=1$ you have $(A-\lambda I)$ row reduces to the identity and therefore $\det(A-\lambda I)\neq 0$, implying that $\lambda=1$ is **not** an eigenvalue in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to throw the 1/7 out in front

Comment: Then your matrix is $\frac{1}{7}A$.  Tell me, is $\frac{1}{7}A-\lambda I$ the same thing as $\frac{1}{7}(A-\lambda I)$?  which did you do by subtracting one from the diagonal?  The first or second?  Which are you supposed to do?

Comment: Oh I've only been subtracting 1/7 instead of 1! I understand now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial for the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&6&3\\6&-3&2\\3&2&-6\end{bmatrix}$ is $\chi(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$ which one finds to be equal to:

$-\lambda^3-7\lambda^2+49\lambda+343$.  After some algebraic manipulation, you will find it can be written as:

$\chi(\lambda)=-(\lambda+7)(\lambda+7)(\lambda-7)$

That implies that for $A$, the eigenvalues are $7,-7,-7$

The actual matrix we are interested in is $(\frac{1}{7} A)$.  By properties of matrices, the eigenvectors of $(\frac{1}{7} A)$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $A$ and the corresponding eigenvalues of $(\frac{1}{7} A)$ are $\frac{1}{7}$ times the eigenvalues of $A$.  That is to say, the eigenvalues of $(\frac{1}{7} A)$ are $1,-1,-1$

We try to find the eigenvector of $1$ for $(\frac{1}{7}A)$.  This is the same as trying to find the eigenvector of $7$ for $A$.

So, we row reduce $A-7I$  (*not $A-I$*).  I.e. row reduce $\begin{bmatrix}2-7&6&3\\6&-3-7&2\\3&2&-6-7\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-5&6&3\\6&-10&2\\3&2&-13\end{bmatrix}$

[Completing the rowreduction process](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B-5,6,3%7D,%7B6,-10,2%7D,%7B3,2,-13%7D%7D), one sees it row reduces to $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3\\0&1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ implying an eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ (*and so the eigenspace for the eigenvalue is the span of this vector*)